# Where are user defined functions stored in MS SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008, user-defined-functions

I want to be able to see the code associated with the User Defined Function. I can see the name etc by doing the following,

```
select * from information_schema.routines where routine_type='function'
```

Which is all fine and dandy but I can actually see the code. Do I need to do this in SQL Server Management Studio, and if so how?

Thanks for all the help, I'm a noob when it comes to IIS/MS SQL stuff.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) look under the Programmability\Functions branch.

[image]

Since you asked, here is how to do it in SQL, not that it will help you if you don't have permissions.

```
EXEC sp_HelpText 'someUserDefinedFunction'
```

Comment: I've looked here and I see no User Defined functions under any of those folders.

Comment: Oh I forgot to mention as well, I may be missing permissions -- if they are guarded by permissions not pertaining to the DB. I have full permissions on the DB but if the defined functions are outside the DB I may have problems. Is there anyway to get the code via an SQL query?

Comment: If you don't have permissions you aren't going to be able to circumvent them just by using a query.