# Cannot locate user defined functions in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, function, ssms, user-defined-functions

First time using SQL Server 2008 this morning.

I am trying to find a user defined function that I created. I cannot locate it in the "Programmability>Functions" branch of the object explorer. Here is what that branch looks like:

[image: Functions Branch]

There do not seem to be any "user defined functions" and I don't know if any of the particular branches should house that. I have been granted database owner rights to the database, so I don't believe it is a permissions issue...

I was able to retrieve the full text of the function using the `'EXEC sp_HelpText 'someUserDefinedFunction''` that was listed [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8812197/where-are-user-defined-functions-stored-in-ms-sql-server-2008) about finding user defined functions. That thread did not provide enough information for me to locate my function in object explorer or edit my function again using SMSS. Please see [the full screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jAwtm.png) of my SQL Server 2008 Management Studio instance with the return from the `sp_HelpText` query for additional context.

The function works just fine when it is called. I retrieved this function from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10914576/tsql-split-string) about splitting delimited text.

I am hoping to find a location in the interface that displays all the user defined functions!

Comment: check under "Table-valued Functions"

Comment: @a1ex07 You're right! I was actually just coming back to this topic to note that... Forgive how green I am - why is it in that branch? This is day #1 for me...

Comment: @a1ex07 Also, if you want to go ahead and answer, I'll give you credit for it. As simple as this question is, I googled for about 30 minutes and never found anything that directly answered it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "user defined functions" menu in SSMS. All functions except system are user defined. Based on return type you will find your function in "Table-valued", "Scalar-valued", or "Aggregate" (the latest is not really different from "Scalar-valued" in terms of return type though, but it can be used for aggregation). In your case check "Table-valued"